# How to get pixel values/cell values for stored raster files in postgis?

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql, postgis-raster

Raster files in tiff format are storing into database.However I gets only an attribute table. 
Is there any way to retrieve pixel values/cell values in the table.

I have used raster2pgsql command for storing.

Comment: http://www.postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PostGIS manual](http://www.postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html), `ST_Value()` returns

> ... the value of a given band in a given columnx, rowy pixel or at
>   a particular geometric point. Band numbers start at 1 and assumed to
>   be 1 if not specified. If exclude_nodata_value is set to false, then
>   all pixels include nodata pixels are considered to intersect and
>   return value. If exclude_nodata_value is not passed in then reads it
>   from metadata of raster.

Synopsis

```
double precision ST_Value
  (raster rast, geometry pt, boolean exclude_nodata_value=true);

double precision ST_Value
  (raster rast, integer bandnum, geometry pt, boolean exclude_nodata_value=true);

double precision ST_Value
  (raster rast, integer columnx, integer rowy, boolean exclude_nodata_value=true);

double precision ST_Value
  (raster rast, integer bandnum, integer columnx, integer rowy, boolean exclude_nodata_value=true);
```

Comment: I am not getting exact difference between ST_Value and ST_Valuecount

Comment: They're completely different: ST_Value returns individual value for a given pixel/point location. ST_Value returns  pixel statistics regarding a given value.